# why I got TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not int in NN?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am writing a NN in pytorch. I have a list of tensors as input i.e. I created a list Y by appending 1000 tensor vectors(linear tensors) of size 3072. So, each Y[i] is a linear tensor of size 3072. Now, when I defined train_loader as

```
train_loader= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Y, batch_size= 5, shuffle= False)
```

Now, when I defined my NN, in training as:

```
epochs = 10

train_loss_list = []
test_loss_list = []

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    ### =====TRAINING=====
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    with tqdm(train_loader, unit="batch") as train_epoch_pbar:
        for data, _ in enumerate(train_epoch_pbar):
            train_epoch_pbar.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch}")
            #data = data.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(data)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, Con)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-73ca0f1b0caa> in <module>
     14 
     15             optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 16             outputs = model(data)
     17             loss = loss_function(outputs, Con)
     18             loss.backward()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-86-4f58fb599c6f> in forward(self, input)
     15 
     16     def forward(self, input):
---> 17         x= self.decoder(input)
     18 
     19         print(x.size())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
    117     def forward(self, input):
    118         for module in self:
--> 119             input = module(input)
    120         return input
    121 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py in forward(self, input)
     92 
     93     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 94         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     95 
     96     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not int
```

BTW, my input tensors are from CIFAR10 dataset which were normalized to [0,1]. So, the error make no sense to me. Also, if I do not comment the code ```data= data.to(device) in coding, get similar error on that line that *int has no attribute to.*. Seems that my network takes elements of my list Y as integer. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unpacking the enumerate incorrectly.

`for data, _ in enumerate(train_epoch_pbar):`

The first value in enumerate is the index.

```py
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(index, value)
```

outputs

```py
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

The errors are correct - you are passing the integer index value in as your data.